# Mostrar/ocultar boton de tarjeta en react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Lo que deseo es mostrar el boton de eliminar solo para el segundo opcion pero como lo estoy implementando sigue saliendo en los 2 opciones,como podria solucionarlo.

codigo primera opcion

```
 const items = {};
this.state.usuarios.map((usuarioTemp) => {
  if (this.state.selected == usuarioTemp.date) {
    items[this.state.selected] = [
      {
        name:
          "Nombre: " +
          usuarioTemp.nombre +
          "\n" +
          "Celular: " +
          usuarioTemp.celular +
          "\n" +
          "Direccion :" +
          usuarioTemp.direccion,
        conditionally: { isDeletable: false },
      },
      
    ];
  }
});
```

Codigo segunda opcion:

```
 this.state.usuariosAgenda.map((usuarioTemp2) => {
  if (this.state.selected == usuarioTemp2.date) {
    items[this.state.selected] = [
      {
        name:
          "Nombre: " +
          usuarioTemp2.nombre +
          "\n" +
          "Celular: " +
          usuarioTemp2.celular +
          "\n" +
          "Direccion :" +
          usuarioTemp2.direccion +
          "\n" +
          "Evento :" +
          usuarioTemp2.eventos,
          conditionally: { isDeletable: true },
      },
    ];
  }
});
```

Uso `conditionally` en el renderizado de las card:

```
  renderItem(item) {
return (
  <TouchableOpacity
    style={[styles.item, { height: item.height }]}
    onPress={() => alert(item.name)}
  >
    <Card>
      <CardContent text={item.name} />

      {item.conditionally && 
        <CardAction separator={true} inColumn={false}>
          <CardButton
            title="Delete"
            color="purple"
              onPress={this.eliminarEvento.bind(this)} 
          />
        </CardAction>
      }
    </Card>
  </TouchableOpacity>
 );
}
```

estoy usando la libreria de calendario [React native calendar](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**conditionally** es un objeto  **{ isDeletable: true }**
puedes cambiar estructura de esto

```
conditionally: { isDeletable: true }
```

a esto

```
conditionally: true
```

o bien en el render solo añades la llave que te devuelve el true o false y dejas tu código anterior tal como está  **item.conditionally.isDeletable**

```
{
    item.conditionally.isDeletable && 
    <CardAction separator={true} inColumn={false}>
      <CardButton
        title="Delete"
        color="purple"
          onPress={this.eliminarEvento.bind(this)} 
      />
    </CardAction>
  }
```

Comment: se ha solucionado,parece que habia algo en los botones de las card que no dejaba funcionar de forma correcta lo anterior planteado,puse un boton fuera de la card y ya..solucionado